# Android SQLite column value does not exists issue

Tags: android, sqlite, custom-cursor

need help in some wired problem. I have a sqlite table items as following

```
item_id    item_name
1          first
2          second
3          third
```

and so on

this piece of code is inserting item_id and item_name to arrays perfectly fine. But when i assign it to CustomCursorAdapter it through exception

"column 'first' does not exists"

please help I am newbie to Android.

```
        c = db.rawQuery("select item_id as _id, item_name from items", null);
        int i = 0;
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {
            from[i] = c.getString(1);
            to[i] = c.getInt(0);
            Log.i("item ", to[i] + " " + from[i]);
            i++;
        } while (c.moveToNext());
        try {
            CustomCursorAdapter ca = new CustomCursorAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, c, from, to);

            getListView().setAdapter(ca);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Ex ", e.getMessage()); // exception : column 'first' does not exists.
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are setting `from[0] = c.getString(1)`.

`getString()` is **zero-based** so in your case is returning `"first"`. Then you are passing `from` as the `from` parameter of a class (that I guess, extends SimpleCursorAdapter) and then you are receiving this error when the adapter is trying to map this column name. In this case `from` represents the list of column names holding the data to bind to the UI, which is represented by `to`.

Answer (score 0):

in from parameter in

```
CustomCursorAdapter ca = new CustomCursorAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, c, from, to);
```

needed column names as arguments, whereas you are passing column values array to from array, whereas 'to' needed to be id of textviews of layouts these columns to de projected, so in this example id is android.R.id.textview1, so do following:

```
String[] from= new String[]{"item_name"};
int[] to= new int[]{android.R.id.textView1};
```

and then execute your query on these parameters.